# Does deleting a remote branch also delete the local remote-tracking branch?

Tags: git, branch

When I delete a remote Git branch with

```
git push origin --delete branch
```

it seeems that it also removes the local remote-tracking branch (i.e. `origin/branch`). However, I don't see this behavior mentioned in the [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push):

> -d, --delete
>              All listed refs are deleted from the remote repository. This is the same as prefixing all refs with a colon.

Is this expected behavior? Where is it documented?

Comment: I believe it *doesn't* do that by default. I have `fetch.prune` set to `true` so that a later `git fetch` deletes it for me. (This means I haven't tested it in ages.)

Comment: Testing says it does, surprises me, too. I don't see it documented anywhere.  I  could see an argument for either way.